# Swiper slider. Different svg icons as pagination

Tags: slider, swiper.js

Is it possible to render four different svg icons as pagination bullets in Swiper slider?

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/Ресурс 1@2x 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/Ресурс 1@2x 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/Ресурс 1@2x 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/Ресурс 1@2x 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
```

Here is the Swiper js code:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
  paginationClickable: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  centeredSlides: true,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  parallax: false,
  loop: true,
  height: "auto",
  paginationClickable: true,
  effect: "slide",
  disableDraggable: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return '<div class="' + className + '">' + labels[index] + "</div>";
    }
  },
  loop: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
          var containerClass = '.svg-container-' + (index + 1);
          var bulletContainer = document.querySelector(containerClass);
          var bulletSVG = bulletContainer.innerHTML;

          return '<span class="' + className + '">' +
            '<svg width="80" height="80">' +
            bulletSVG +
            '</svg>' +
            '</span>';
        },
      },
    });
```

```css
.swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh; 
}
.swiper-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
}
.swiper-slide {
      width: 100%;
      flex-shrink: 0;
}
.swiper-pagination {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
}
.swiper-pagination span {
      margin: 0 5px;
}
.swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
.swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.custom-svg-container {
      display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/g9d37ee43853a8a490548795d312e738a5fbf8ad25c015c9fe73523a3f7534abcbeb8d362330384acf3093e35c1f89498_1280.png">
        <div class="custom-svg-container svg-container-1">
          <svg width="87" height="87" viewBox="0 0 87 87" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M43.5 85C66.4198 85 85 66.4198 85 43.5C85 20.5802 66.4198 2 43.5 2C20.5802 2 2 20.5802 2 43.5C2 66.4198 20.5802 85 43.5 85Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
<path d="M18.4996 15.9345C21.0943 15.0892 23.7906 14.5957 26.5165 14.467C28.5255 14.372 30.6437 14.4955 32.5102 15.2981C34.3767 16.1008 35.5023 17.6064 36.1482 19.5346C36.88 21.9541 37.2888 24.4597 37.3641 26.9863C37.5113 29.513 37.4733 32.0397 37.4401 34.5853C37.3474 36.2472 37.3712 37.9136 37.5113 39.5722C37.5541 39.9141 37.5778 40.2894 37.9198 40.4366C38.6433 40.6502 39.3994 40.7322 40.152 40.6787C41.2185 40.7057 42.2858 40.6708 43.3483 40.5743C44.2211 40.5358 45.0843 40.376 45.913 40.0993C46.6586 39.8049 46.5114 39.2587 46.4829 38.5178C46.4544 37.7769 46.4496 36.7748 45.8559 36.2476C45.6167 36.0801 45.3465 35.9618 45.0611 35.8999C44.7757 35.8379 44.4808 35.8334 44.1937 35.8866C44.1557 35.8866 44.2174 37.074 44.1937 37.074C44.9346 37.017 45.761 37.074 46.1504 37.8149C46.3874 38.3795 46.4992 38.9887 46.4781 39.6007V38.4323C46.4306 38.874 45.6137 39.0212 45.286 39.0972C44.4042 39.2865 43.5083 39.4025 42.6074 39.4439C41.6778 39.5041 40.7457 39.5168 39.8147 39.482C39.2448 39.482 38.3899 39.5104 37.877 39.235C37.5968 39.083 37.5636 38.76 37.5208 38.4703C37.4528 37.9094 37.4226 37.3445 37.4306 36.7795C37.4306 34.7041 37.4971 32.6286 37.4876 30.5484C37.4876 28.2972 37.4306 26.0412 37.2073 23.7995C37.057 21.6374 36.5897 19.5091 35.8205 17.4828C34.3197 13.8591 30.2875 13.1514 26.7587 13.2844C23.9506 13.3926 21.1711 13.8897 18.4996 14.7615C18.3713 14.7995 18.6088 15.9108 18.4996 15.9488V15.9345Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M32.5432 48.9379C33.1158 48.7752 33.6735 48.5639 34.2102 48.3063C35.0064 47.8889 35.7576 47.3908 36.4519 46.8197C37.8767 45.7559 39.9189 44.9865 41.7047 45.5422C41.9155 45.6092 42.1204 45.6933 42.3174 45.7938C42.4124 45.8413 42.9918 46.302 43.0535 46.2688C43.1153 46.2355 43.1058 46.2023 43.1295 46.1881C43.3557 46.0451 43.5716 45.8864 43.7754 45.7131C44.6747 45.1513 45.7288 44.8885 46.7865 44.9627C49.0425 45.1099 50.9802 46.587 52.5285 48.1163V46.9289C47.2898 47.685 42.006 48.0864 36.7131 48.1305C35.3112 48.1895 33.9078 48.0536 32.5432 47.7269C32.6429 47.7554 32.4292 48.881 32.5432 48.9142C33.7174 49.2035 34.9246 49.3376 36.1337 49.3131C37.777 49.3464 39.4203 49.2846 41.0588 49.1944C44.2124 49.0139 47.3565 48.7195 50.491 48.3585L52.5285 48.1163C52.5595 47.7211 52.5595 47.3241 52.5285 46.9289C50.3581 44.7822 47.0763 42.6973 44.0272 44.3785C43.7472 44.5303 43.4845 44.7118 43.2435 44.92C43.2103 44.9485 43.12 45.0624 43.0773 45.0719C42.9586 45.1004 42.5311 44.7205 42.3934 44.6445C40.6551 43.6946 38.5179 44.3121 36.9363 45.2952C36.1147 45.8081 35.4498 46.4968 34.5617 46.9384C33.9154 47.272 33.2356 47.5363 32.5337 47.7269C32.4387 47.7791 32.6334 48.9142 32.5432 48.9379Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M47.0858 52.5807C44.4404 53.6398 41.2584 53.5639 38.8172 52.0488C37.8673 51.4551 37.2072 50.5908 36.3665 49.8594C35.8916 49.4604 35.3454 49.166 34.8562 48.8098C34.1628 48.3016 33.4314 47.7838 32.5433 47.7458C32.5433 47.7458 32.5195 48.9332 32.5433 48.9332C33.3743 49.0408 34.1545 49.3929 34.785 49.9448C35.2979 50.32 35.8868 50.6288 36.3665 51.0467C37.2072 51.7781 37.8483 52.6425 38.8172 53.2361C41.2584 54.7512 44.4404 54.8272 47.0858 53.7681C47.2283 53.7063 46.9576 52.6282 47.0858 52.5807Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M19.1834 22.2132C20.4803 22.788 21.8498 23.1826 23.2536 23.3863C26.9114 23.9747 30.6487 23.8472 34.2579 23.0111C34.3482 23.0111 34.1819 21.8427 34.2579 21.8237C30.6487 22.6599 26.9114 22.7873 23.2536 22.199C21.8498 21.9953 20.4803 21.6006 19.1834 21.0259C19.3307 21.0971 19.0219 22.1325 19.1834 22.2132Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M48.0785 22.2134C49.2502 22.6185 50.4702 22.8676 51.707 22.9543C54.5736 23.226 57.4633 22.7974 60.1276 21.7052C62.1718 20.8398 64.0467 19.6194 65.6654 18.1004C65.7271 18.0434 65.6654 17.597 65.6654 17.5068C65.6654 17.4165 65.5942 16.9748 65.6654 16.9131C63.5174 18.9348 60.9072 20.3999 58.0626 21.1806C55.218 21.9612 52.2256 22.0337 49.3466 21.3917C48.916 21.2988 48.4924 21.1767 48.0785 21.0261C48.1972 21.0736 47.9408 22.1612 48.0785 22.2134Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M18.6134 16.229C18.1536 20.7344 18.0853 25.2713 18.4091 29.7885C18.5043 31.2981 18.7219 32.7975 19.0598 34.2719C19.3749 35.4431 19.8194 36.5757 20.3849 37.6487C21.8334 40.6313 23.2345 43.6377 24.7305 46.5965C26.291 49.8229 28.0665 52.9408 30.0451 55.929C31.6317 58.2736 33.6991 60.2537 36.11 61.7375C38.9807 63.5739 42.3911 64.3778 45.7797 64.0172C50.3344 63.4377 54.0104 60.6309 57.4015 57.7385C63.2859 52.7327 68.325 46.4207 69.5979 38.6033C69.7451 37.7057 69.8401 36.8033 69.8971 35.8962C69.8971 35.54 69.8733 35.0318 69.8971 34.7515C69.6773 38.376 68.6967 41.9134 67.0189 45.1337C65.2137 48.4567 62.8925 51.4721 60.1419 54.0673C58.6412 55.5198 57.0654 56.8927 55.421 58.1802C53.6733 59.644 51.7314 60.8587 49.6505 61.7897C46.3406 63.1813 42.6293 63.2812 39.2494 62.0699C36.5452 61.0658 34.1078 59.454 32.1253 57.3586C30.0498 55.1644 28.5158 52.424 27.0625 49.8023C25.3527 46.7105 23.7997 43.5332 22.2704 40.3511C21.6482 39.0545 21.0308 37.7532 20.4039 36.4614C19.8561 35.4233 19.4214 34.3294 19.1073 33.1985C18.4399 30.1831 18.1637 27.0944 18.2856 24.0085C18.3189 21.914 18.4186 19.8195 18.6039 17.7298L18.6323 17.4163C18.6703 17.0269 18.5944 16.6232 18.6323 16.229H18.6134Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M12.1019 66.753C14.701 66.1777 17.1406 65.0345 19.2459 63.4054C21.3512 61.7764 23.0701 59.7018 24.2793 57.3303C25.3885 54.8176 25.9502 52.0977 25.9273 49.3513C25.9273 49.0711 25.9273 48.7909 25.9273 48.5107C25.9273 48.2827 25.9273 48.3397 25.9273 48.5107C25.8751 53.0796 24.3078 57.5345 21.0165 60.7688C18.959 62.759 16.4734 64.2521 13.75 65.1335C13.2147 65.3199 12.6672 65.4691 12.1114 65.5799C12.0307 65.5799 12.1732 66.7578 12.1114 66.7673L12.1019 66.753Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M68.2918 74.0195C65.7746 72.1578 63.9129 69.1134 63.0295 66.1641C62.8286 65.5068 62.6699 64.8374 62.5546 64.1598C62.4976 63.7989 62.4548 63.4379 62.4263 63.0722C62.4263 62.8395 62.3931 62.5973 62.3836 62.3693C62.3741 62.1414 62.3836 62.3978 62.3836 62.4311C62.3836 62.2886 62.3836 62.1461 62.3836 62.0036C62.5673 60.1008 62.9169 58.2176 63.4284 56.3756C63.9889 54.0009 64.573 51.6263 65.3614 49.3276C65.5159 48.7078 65.7608 48.114 66.0881 47.5655C66.2781 47.3091 65.9029 46.6156 66.0881 46.3782C65.8008 46.8567 65.5818 47.3731 65.4374 47.9123C64.6415 50.301 63.971 52.7296 63.4284 55.1883C62.9107 57.0436 62.5595 58.9414 62.3788 60.8591C62.2798 62.3054 62.3259 63.7581 62.5166 65.1952C62.9107 67.778 63.9333 70.2244 65.4944 72.3193C66.2699 73.4158 67.201 74.3933 68.2586 75.2211C68.0733 75.0834 68.4533 74.1763 68.2586 74.0338L68.2918 74.0195Z" fill="red"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/g9d37ee43853a8a490548795d312e738a5fbf8ad25c015c9fe73523a3f7534abcbeb8d362330384acf3093e35c1f89498_1280.png">
        <div class="custom-svg-container svg-container-2">
          <svg width="87" height="87" viewBox="0 0 87 87" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M43.5 85C66.4198 85 85 66.4198 85 43.5C85 20.5802 66.4198 2 43.5 2C20.5802 2 2 20.5802 2 43.5C2 66.4198 20.5802 85 43.5 85Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
<path d="M18.4996 15.9345C21.0943 15.0892 23.7906 14.5957 26.5165 14.467C28.5255 14.372 30.6437 14.4955 32.5102 15.2981C34.3767 16.1008 35.5023 17.6064 36.1482 19.5346C36.88 21.9541 37.2888 24.4597 37.3641 26.9863C37.5113 29.513 37.4733 32.0397 37.4401 34.5853C37.3474 36.2472 37.3712 37.9136 37.5113 39.5722C37.5541 39.9141 37.5778 40.2894 37.9198 40.4366C38.6433 40.6502 39.3994 40.7322 40.152 40.6787C41.2185 40.7057 42.2858 40.6708 43.3483 40.5743C44.2211 40.5358 45.0843 40.376 45.913 40.0993C46.6586 39.8049 46.5114 39.2587 46.4829 38.5178C46.4544 37.7769 46.4496 36.7748 45.8559 36.2476C45.6167 36.0801 45.3465 35.9618 45.0611 35.8999C44.7757 35.8379 44.4808 35.8334 44.1937 35.8866C44.1557 35.8866 44.2174 37.074 44.1937 37.074C44.9346 37.017 45.761 37.074 46.1504 37.8149C46.3874 38.3795 46.4992 38.9887 46.4781 39.6007V38.4323C46.4306 38.874 45.6137 39.0212 45.286 39.0972C44.4042 39.2865 43.5083 39.4025 42.6074 39.4439C41.6778 39.5041 40.7457 39.5168 39.8147 39.482C39.2448 39.482 38.3899 39.5104 37.877 39.235C37.5968 39.083 37.5636 38.76 37.5208 38.4703C37.4528 37.9094 37.4226 37.3445 37.4306 36.7795C37.4306 34.7041 37.4971 32.6286 37.4876 30.5484C37.4876 28.2972 37.4306 26.0412 37.2073 23.7995C37.057 21.6374 36.5897 19.5091 35.8205 17.4828C34.3197 13.8591 30.2875 13.1514 26.7587 13.2844C23.9506 13.3926 21.1711 13.8897 18.4996 14.7615C18.3713 14.7995 18.6088 15.9108 18.4996 15.9488V15.9345Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M32.5432 48.9379C33.1158 48.7752 33.6735 48.5639 34.2102 48.3063C35.0064 47.8889 35.7576 47.3908 36.4519 46.8197C37.8767 45.7559 39.9189 44.9865 41.7047 45.5422C41.9155 45.6092 42.1204 45.6933 42.3174 45.7938C42.4124 45.8413 42.9918 46.302 43.0535 46.2688C43.1153 46.2355 43.1058 46.2023 43.1295 46.1881C43.3557 46.0451 43.5716 45.8864 43.7754 45.7131C44.6747 45.1513 45.7288 44.8885 46.7865 44.9627C49.0425 45.1099 50.9802 46.587 52.5285 48.1163V46.9289C47.2898 47.685 42.006 48.0864 36.7131 48.1305C35.3112 48.1895 33.9078 48.0536 32.5432 47.7269C32.6429 47.7554 32.4292 48.881 32.5432 48.9142C33.7174 49.2035 34.9246 49.3376 36.1337 49.3131C37.777 49.3464 39.4203 49.2846 41.0588 49.1944C44.2124 49.0139 47.3565 48.7195 50.491 48.3585L52.5285 48.1163C52.5595 47.7211 52.5595 47.3241 52.5285 46.9289C50.3581 44.7822 47.0763 42.6973 44.0272 44.3785C43.7472 44.5303 43.4845 44.7118 43.2435 44.92C43.2103 44.9485 43.12 45.0624 43.0773 45.0719C42.9586 45.1004 42.5311 44.7205 42.3934 44.6445C40.6551 43.6946 38.5179 44.3121 36.9363 45.2952C36.1147 45.8081 35.4498 46.4968 34.5617 46.9384C33.9154 47.272 33.2356 47.5363 32.5337 47.7269C32.4387 47.7791 32.6334 48.9142 32.5432 48.9379Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M47.0858 52.5807C44.4404 53.6398 41.2584 53.5639 38.8172 52.0488C37.8673 51.4551 37.2072 50.5908 36.3665 49.8594C35.8916 49.4604 35.3454 49.166 34.8562 48.8098C34.1628 48.3016 33.4314 47.7838 32.5433 47.7458C32.5433 47.7458 32.5195 48.9332 32.5433 48.9332C33.3743 49.0408 34.1545 49.3929 34.785 49.9448C35.2979 50.32 35.8868 50.6288 36.3665 51.0467C37.2072 51.7781 37.8483 52.6425 38.8172 53.2361C41.2584 54.7512 44.4404 54.8272 47.0858 53.7681C47.2283 53.7063 46.9576 52.6282 47.0858 52.5807Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M19.1834 22.2132C20.4803 22.788 21.8498 23.1826 23.2536 23.3863C26.9114 23.9747 30.6487 23.8472 34.2579 23.0111C34.3482 23.0111 34.1819 21.8427 34.2579 21.8237C30.6487 22.6599 26.9114 22.7873 23.2536 22.199C21.8498 21.9953 20.4803 21.6006 19.1834 21.0259C19.3307 21.0971 19.0219 22.1325 19.1834 22.2132Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M48.0785 22.2134C49.2502 22.6185 50.4702 22.8676 51.707 22.9543C54.5736 23.226 57.4633 22.7974 60.1276 21.7052C62.1718 20.8398 64.0467 19.6194 65.6654 18.1004C65.7271 18.0434 65.6654 17.597 65.6654 17.5068C65.6654 17.4165 65.5942 16.9748 65.6654 16.9131C63.5174 18.9348 60.9072 20.3999 58.0626 21.1806C55.218 21.9612 52.2256 22.0337 49.3466 21.3917C48.916 21.2988 48.4924 21.1767 48.0785 21.0261C48.1972 21.0736 47.9408 22.1612 48.0785 22.2134Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M18.6134 16.229C18.1536 20.7344 18.0853 25.2713 18.4091 29.7885C18.5043 31.2981 18.7219 32.7975 19.0598 34.2719C19.3749 35.4431 19.8194 36.5757 20.3849 37.6487C21.8334 40.6313 23.2345 43.6377 24.7305 46.5965C26.291 49.8229 28.0665 52.9408 30.0451 55.929C31.6317 58.2736 33.6991 60.2537 36.11 61.7375C38.9807 63.5739 42.3911 64.3778 45.7797 64.0172C50.3344 63.4377 54.0104 60.6309 57.4015 57.7385C63.2859 52.7327 68.325 46.4207 69.5979 38.6033C69.7451 37.7057 69.8401 36.8033 69.8971 35.8962C69.8971 35.54 69.8733 35.0318 69.8971 34.7515C69.6773 38.376 68.6967 41.9134 67.0189 45.1337C65.2137 48.4567 62.8925 51.4721 60.1419 54.0673C58.6412 55.5198 57.0654 56.8927 55.421 58.1802C53.6733 59.644 51.7314 60.8587 49.6505 61.7897C46.3406 63.1813 42.6293 63.2812 39.2494 62.0699C36.5452 61.0658 34.1078 59.454 32.1253 57.3586C30.0498 55.1644 28.5158 52.424 27.0625 49.8023C25.3527 46.7105 23.7997 43.5332 22.2704 40.3511C21.6482 39.0545 21.0308 37.7532 20.4039 36.4614C19.8561 35.4233 19.4214 34.3294 19.1073 33.1985C18.4399 30.1831 18.1637 27.0944 18.2856 24.0085C18.3189 21.914 18.4186 19.8195 18.6039 17.7298L18.6323 17.4163C18.6703 17.0269 18.5944 16.6232 18.6323 16.229H18.6134Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M12.1019 66.753C14.701 66.1777 17.1406 65.0345 19.2459 63.4054C21.3512 61.7764 23.0701 59.7018 24.2793 57.3303C25.3885 54.8176 25.9502 52.0977 25.9273 49.3513C25.9273 49.0711 25.9273 48.7909 25.9273 48.5107C25.9273 48.2827 25.9273 48.3397 25.9273 48.5107C25.8751 53.0796 24.3078 57.5345 21.0165 60.7688C18.959 62.759 16.4734 64.2521 13.75 65.1335C13.2147 65.3199 12.6672 65.4691 12.1114 65.5799C12.0307 65.5799 12.1732 66.7578 12.1114 66.7673L12.1019 66.753Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M68.2918 74.0195C65.7746 72.1578 63.9129 69.1134 63.0295 66.1641C62.8286 65.5068 62.6699 64.8374 62.5546 64.1598C62.4976 63.7989 62.4548 63.4379 62.4263 63.0722C62.4263 62.8395 62.3931 62.5973 62.3836 62.3693C62.3741 62.1414 62.3836 62.3978 62.3836 62.4311C62.3836 62.2886 62.3836 62.1461 62.3836 62.0036C62.5673 60.1008 62.9169 58.2176 63.4284 56.3756C63.9889 54.0009 64.573 51.6263 65.3614 49.3276C65.5159 48.7078 65.7608 48.114 66.0881 47.5655C66.2781 47.3091 65.9029 46.6156 66.0881 46.3782C65.8008 46.8567 65.5818 47.3731 65.4374 47.9123C64.6415 50.301 63.971 52.7296 63.4284 55.1883C62.9107 57.0436 62.5595 58.9414 62.3788 60.8591C62.2798 62.3054 62.3259 63.7581 62.5166 65.1952C62.9107 67.778 63.9333 70.2244 65.4944 72.3193C66.2699 73.4158 67.201 74.3933 68.2586 75.2211C68.0733 75.0834 68.4533 74.1763 68.2586 74.0338L68.2918 74.0195Z" fill="red"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/g9d37ee43853a8a490548795d312e738a5fbf8ad25c015c9fe73523a3f7534abcbeb8d362330384acf3093e35c1f89498_1280.png">
        <div class="custom-svg-container svg-container-3">
          <svg width="87" height="87" viewBox="0 0 87 87" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M43.5 85C66.4198 85 85 66.4198 85 43.5C85 20.5802 66.4198 2 43.5 2C20.5802 2 2 20.5802 2 43.5C2 66.4198 20.5802 85 43.5 85Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
<path d="M18.4996 15.9345C21.0943 15.0892 23.7906 14.5957 26.5165 14.467C28.5255 14.372 30.6437 14.4955 32.5102 15.2981C34.3767 16.1008 35.5023 17.6064 36.1482 19.5346C36.88 21.9541 37.2888 24.4597 37.3641 26.9863C37.5113 29.513 37.4733 32.0397 37.4401 34.5853C37.3474 36.2472 37.3712 37.9136 37.5113 39.5722C37.5541 39.9141 37.5778 40.2894 37.9198 40.4366C38.6433 40.6502 39.3994 40.7322 40.152 40.6787C41.2185 40.7057 42.2858 40.6708 43.3483 40.5743C44.2211 40.5358 45.0843 40.376 45.913 40.0993C46.6586 39.8049 46.5114 39.2587 46.4829 38.5178C46.4544 37.7769 46.4496 36.7748 45.8559 36.2476C45.6167 36.0801 45.3465 35.9618 45.0611 35.8999C44.7757 35.8379 44.4808 35.8334 44.1937 35.8866C44.1557 35.8866 44.2174 37.074 44.1937 37.074C44.9346 37.017 45.761 37.074 46.1504 37.8149C46.3874 38.3795 46.4992 38.9887 46.4781 39.6007V38.4323C46.4306 38.874 45.6137 39.0212 45.286 39.0972C44.4042 39.2865 43.5083 39.4025 42.6074 39.4439C41.6778 39.5041 40.7457 39.5168 39.8147 39.482C39.2448 39.482 38.3899 39.5104 37.877 39.235C37.5968 39.083 37.5636 38.76 37.5208 38.4703C37.4528 37.9094 37.4226 37.3445 37.4306 36.7795C37.4306 34.7041 37.4971 32.6286 37.4876 30.5484C37.4876 28.2972 37.4306 26.0412 37.2073 23.7995C37.057 21.6374 36.5897 19.5091 35.8205 17.4828C34.3197 13.8591 30.2875 13.1514 26.7587 13.2844C23.9506 13.3926 21.1711 13.8897 18.4996 14.7615C18.3713 14.7995 18.6088 15.9108 18.4996 15.9488V15.9345Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M32.5432 48.9379C33.1158 48.7752 33.6735 48.5639 34.2102 48.3063C35.0064 47.8889 35.7576 47.3908 36.4519 46.8197C37.8767 45.7559 39.9189 44.9865 41.7047 45.5422C41.9155 45.6092 42.1204 45.6933 42.3174 45.7938C42.4124 45.8413 42.9918 46.302 43.0535 46.2688C43.1153 46.2355 43.1058 46.2023 43.1295 46.1881C43.3557 46.0451 43.5716 45.8864 43.7754 45.7131C44.6747 45.1513 45.7288 44.8885 46.7865 44.9627C49.0425 45.1099 50.9802 46.587 52.5285 48.1163V46.9289C47.2898 47.685 42.006 48.0864 36.7131 48.1305C35.3112 48.1895 33.9078 48.0536 32.5432 47.7269C32.6429 47.7554 32.4292 48.881 32.5432 48.9142C33.7174 49.2035 34.9246 49.3376 36.1337 49.3131C37.777 49.3464 39.4203 49.2846 41.0588 49.1944C44.2124 49.0139 47.3565 48.7195 50.491 48.3585L52.5285 48.1163C52.5595 47.7211 52.5595 47.3241 52.5285 46.9289C50.3581 44.7822 47.0763 42.6973 44.0272 44.3785C43.7472 44.5303 43.4845 44.7118 43.2435 44.92C43.2103 44.9485 43.12 45.0624 43.0773 45.0719C42.9586 45.1004 42.5311 44.7205 42.3934 44.6445C40.6551 43.6946 38.5179 44.3121 36.9363 45.2952C36.1147 45.8081 35.4498 46.4968 34.5617 46.9384C33.9154 47.272 33.2356 47.5363 32.5337 47.7269C32.4387 47.7791 32.6334 48.9142 32.5432 48.9379Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M47.0858 52.5807C44.4404 53.6398 41.2584 53.5639 38.8172 52.0488C37.8673 51.4551 37.2072 50.5908 36.3665 49.8594C35.8916 49.4604 35.3454 49.166 34.8562 48.8098C34.1628 48.3016 33.4314 47.7838 32.5433 47.7458C32.5433 47.7458 32.5195 48.9332 32.5433 48.9332C33.3743 49.0408 34.1545 49.3929 34.785 49.9448C35.2979 50.32 35.8868 50.6288 36.3665 51.0467C37.2072 51.7781 37.8483 52.6425 38.8172 53.2361C41.2584 54.7512 44.4404 54.8272 47.0858 53.7681C47.2283 53.7063 46.9576 52.6282 47.0858 52.5807Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M19.1834 22.2132C20.4803 22.788 21.8498 23.1826 23.2536 23.3863C26.9114 23.9747 30.6487 23.8472 34.2579 23.0111C34.3482 23.0111 34.1819 21.8427 34.2579 21.8237C30.6487 22.6599 26.9114 22.7873 23.2536 22.199C21.8498 21.9953 20.4803 21.6006 19.1834 21.0259C19.3307 21.0971 19.0219 22.1325 19.1834 22.2132Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M48.0785 22.2134C49.2502 22.6185 50.4702 22.8676 51.707 22.9543C54.5736 23.226 57.4633 22.7974 60.1276 21.7052C62.1718 20.8398 64.0467 19.6194 65.6654 18.1004C65.7271 18.0434 65.6654 17.597 65.6654 17.5068C65.6654 17.4165 65.5942 16.9748 65.6654 16.9131C63.5174 18.9348 60.9072 20.3999 58.0626 21.1806C55.218 21.9612 52.2256 22.0337 49.3466 21.3917C48.916 21.2988 48.4924 21.1767 48.0785 21.0261C48.1972 21.0736 47.9408 22.1612 48.0785 22.2134Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M18.6134 16.229C18.1536 20.7344 18.0853 25.2713 18.4091 29.7885C18.5043 31.2981 18.7219 32.7975 19.0598 34.2719C19.3749 35.4431 19.8194 36.5757 20.3849 37.6487C21.8334 40.6313 23.2345 43.6377 24.7305 46.5965C26.291 49.8229 28.0665 52.9408 30.0451 55.929C31.6317 58.2736 33.6991 60.2537 36.11 61.7375C38.9807 63.5739 42.3911 64.3778 45.7797 64.0172C50.3344 63.4377 54.0104 60.6309 57.4015 57.7385C63.2859 52.7327 68.325 46.4207 69.5979 38.6033C69.7451 37.7057 69.8401 36.8033 69.8971 35.8962C69.8971 35.54 69.8733 35.0318 69.8971 34.7515C69.6773 38.376 68.6967 41.9134 67.0189 45.1337C65.2137 48.4567 62.8925 51.4721 60.1419 54.0673C58.6412 55.5198 57.0654 56.8927 55.421 58.1802C53.6733 59.644 51.7314 60.8587 49.6505 61.7897C46.3406 63.1813 42.6293 63.2812 39.2494 62.0699C36.5452 61.0658 34.1078 59.454 32.1253 57.3586C30.0498 55.1644 28.5158 52.424 27.0625 49.8023C25.3527 46.7105 23.7997 43.5332 22.2704 40.3511C21.6482 39.0545 21.0308 37.7532 20.4039 36.4614C19.8561 35.4233 19.4214 34.3294 19.1073 33.1985C18.4399 30.1831 18.1637 27.0944 18.2856 24.0085C18.3189 21.914 18.4186 19.8195 18.6039 17.7298L18.6323 17.4163C18.6703 17.0269 18.5944 16.6232 18.6323 16.229H18.6134Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M12.1019 66.753C14.701 66.1777 17.1406 65.0345 19.2459 63.4054C21.3512 61.7764 23.0701 59.7018 24.2793 57.3303C25.3885 54.8176 25.9502 52.0977 25.9273 49.3513C25.9273 49.0711 25.9273 48.7909 25.9273 48.5107C25.9273 48.2827 25.9273 48.3397 25.9273 48.5107C25.8751 53.0796 24.3078 57.5345 21.0165 60.7688C18.959 62.759 16.4734 64.2521 13.75 65.1335C13.2147 65.3199 12.6672 65.4691 12.1114 65.5799C12.0307 65.5799 12.1732 66.7578 12.1114 66.7673L12.1019 66.753Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M68.2918 74.0195C65.7746 72.1578 63.9129 69.1134 63.0295 66.1641C62.8286 65.5068 62.6699 64.8374 62.5546 64.1598C62.4976 63.7989 62.4548 63.4379 62.4263 63.0722C62.4263 62.8395 62.3931 62.5973 62.3836 62.3693C62.3741 62.1414 62.3836 62.3978 62.3836 62.4311C62.3836 62.2886 62.3836 62.1461 62.3836 62.0036C62.5673 60.1008 62.9169 58.2176 63.4284 56.3756C63.9889 54.0009 64.573 51.6263 65.3614 49.3276C65.5159 48.7078 65.7608 48.114 66.0881 47.5655C66.2781 47.3091 65.9029 46.6156 66.0881 46.3782C65.8008 46.8567 65.5818 47.3731 65.4374 47.9123C64.6415 50.301 63.971 52.7296 63.4284 55.1883C62.9107 57.0436 62.5595 58.9414 62.3788 60.8591C62.2798 62.3054 62.3259 63.7581 62.5166 65.1952C62.9107 67.778 63.9333 70.2244 65.4944 72.3193C66.2699 73.4158 67.201 74.3933 68.2586 75.2211C68.0733 75.0834 68.4533 74.1763 68.2586 74.0338L68.2918 74.0195Z" fill="red"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (don't set default css from Swiper.js):

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
      renderBullet: function (index, className) {
        var bulletSVGs = [
          '<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="8" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />',
          '<rect width="16" height="16" x="2" y="2" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="blue" />',
          '<polygon points="8,2 16,16 2,16" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="green" />',
          '<rect width="16" height="10" x="2" y="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="orange" />'
        ];

        return '<span class="' + className + '">' +
          '<svg width="30" height="30">' +
          bulletSVGs[index] +
          '</svg>' +
          '</span>';
      },
    },
  });
```

```css
.swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .swiper-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      width: 100%;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }

    .swiper-pagination {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .swiper-pagination span {
      margin: 0 5px;
    }
    .swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet {
      opacity: 0.5;
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    }
    .swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/gd3b64f5ae0d44b1d9950c78f3d8bde5eb4dd83504246edccd0b5023f2a66d067e7b11b19f6e771ece0404271c3d2a7d7_1280.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/g5a4d289c4306b54d5c057572555579f1976dcda16472d033f9bb5effa81572aed6130e3314537009dad03786e3d7f2a5_1280.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/g8fb896083e20e147673156fd4afb82867dd5a6fd8957e88570f82ac29ce0ad525f306b5ab0ae14235904d7e57ea61f06_1280.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/g57d613f2d4d0f27cf6f63458b9b5158caf091c290db489820e574ebdc26a8f4d6e2d358941f0eff0d885d703f58e3fab_1280.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you for your time. Good work.

Comment: It works perfectly but it doesn't render something big like my svg icon that has many paths in there. Do you have any ideas how to render this?